# Python - Zeep SOAP Complex Header

Tags: python-3.x, soap, zeep

I'd like to pass "Complex" Header to a SOAP service with zeep library

Here's what it should look like

```
 <soapenv:Header>
      <something:myVar1>FOO</something:myVar1>
      <something:myVar2>JAM</something:myVar2>
 </soapenv:Header>
```

I guess that I succeed in sending a header this way

```
header = xsd.Element(
    '{http://urlofthews}Header',
        xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
        '{http://urlofthews}myVar1',
        xsd.String()),
        xsd.Element(
        '{http://urlofthews}myVar2',
        xsd.String())
        ])
    )

header_value = header(myVar1='FOO',myVar2='JAM')
print (header_value)
datasoap=client.service.UserRessourcesCatalog(requete,_soapheaders=[header_value])
```

But I don't get how to declare and pass the namespace "something" in my Header with the XSD.

Any Help ?

Thx by advance.

Best Regards

---

As mentionned in the documentation

http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/headers.html

"Another option is to pass an lxml Element object. This is generally useful if the wsdl doesn’t define a soap header but the server does expect it."

which is my case so I tried

```
try:
        import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
    except ImportError:
        import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    ET.register_namespace('something', 'http://urlofthews')

    headerXML = ET.Element("soapenv:Header")
    var1 = ET.SubElement(headerXML, "something:myVar1")
    var1.text = "FOO"
    var2 = ET.SubElement(headerXML, "something:myVar2")
    var2.text = "JAM"


headerDict=xmltodict.parse(ET.tostring(headerXML))
print (json.dumps(headerDict))

    datasoap=client.service.UserRessourcesCatalog(requete,_soapheaders=headerDict)
```

But I get : ComplexType() got an unexpected keyword argument u'soapenv:Header'. Signature: ``

Answer (score 31):

I recently encountered this problem, and here is how I solved it.

Say you have a 'Security' header that looks as follows...

```
<env:Header>
<Security>
    <UsernameToken>
        <Username>__USERNAME__</Username>
        <Password>__PWD__</Password>
    </UsernameToken>
    <ServiceAccessToken>        
        <AccessLicenseNumber>__KEY__</AccessLicenseNumber>
    </ServiceAccessToken>
</Security>
</env:Header>
```

In order to send this header in the zeep client's request, you would need to do the following:

```
header = zeep.xsd.Element(
            'Security',
            zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                zeep.xsd.Element(
                    'UsernameToken',
                    zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                        zeep.xsd.Element('Username',zeep.xsd.String()),
                        zeep.xsd.Element('Password',zeep.xsd.String()),
                    ])
                ),
                zeep.xsd.Element(
                    'ServiceAccessToken',
                    zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                        zeep.xsd.Element('AccessLicenseNumber',zeep.xsd.String()),
                    ])
                ),
            ])
        )

header_value = header(UsernameToken={'Username':'test_user','Password':'testing'},UPSServiceAccessToken={'AccessLicenseNumber':'test_pwd'})

client.service.method_name_goes_here(
                    _soapheaders=[header_value],#other method data goes here
                )
```

Comment: Thx for your explanation Oblivion

Comment: You are welcome. Since it is still marked as a 'zeep' question, is there any chance you were able to confirm my answer works - so you can accept it?

Comment: This solution worked really well for me. Thank you very much, there are no examples about complex headers for soap requests using Zeep.

Comment: Glad it helped you out SergioMP.

Comment: How would this be written if the spec did not contain the enveloping 'Security' element and 'env:Header' just retained the 'UsernameToken' and 'ServiceAccessToken'? Is it just as simple as removing the outside zeep.xsd.Element? I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201921/in-python-how-to-set-soapheaders-for-zeep-using-dictionaries)

Answer (score 2):

Thx Oblivion02.

I finally use a raw method

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://blablabla">
<soapenv:Header>
<something:myVar1>FOO</something:myVar1>
<something:myVar2>JAM</something:myVar2>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
          ...
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(wsdl,data=body,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Do you think you could accept my answer? The question is still tagged as a zeep question - so while your answer works using the raw method - the answer I provided uses the zeep library.