# In Python, how to set _soapheaders for Zeep using Dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, xsd, header, zeep

In working with a SOAP api, the wsdl spec describes the api key passed in the header in a complex namespaced structure as well as additional non-namespaced XML that relates to a paging mechanism for accessing bulk results successively:

**Specification**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="https://webservice_address_here">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns:apiKey>
      <api_key>***</api_key>
    </ns:apiKey>
    <pager>
      <page>1</page>
      <per_page>100</per_page>
    </pager>
  </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**API Documentation**:

> Pagination; this method returns paginated results. To specify pages or
> results per page, use the pager header:
>
> ```
> <soapenv:Header>
>   <ns:pager>
>     <page>1</page>
>     <per_page>100</per_page>
>   </ns:pager>
> </soapenv:Header> Max per page is 100
> ```
>
> Pagination information is returned in a pager header:
>
> ```
> <soapenv:Header>
>   <ns:pager>
>     <page>1</page>
>     <per_page>100</per_page>
>     <next_page>2</next_page>
>     <page_items>100</page_items>
>     <total_items>2829</total_items>
>     <total_pages>29</total_pages>
>   </ns:pager>
> </soapenv:Header>
> ```

The answer, [How to set soap headers in zeep when header has multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410844/how-to-set-soap-headers-in-zeep-when-header-has-multiple-elements), describes a similar scenario, without the namespace "ns" but with "acm." I have not been successful in using this method.

**This works, allowing access to the api but without the pager making it mostly useless for any methods that return more than 100 results:**

```
from zeep import Client, xsd

# Generate the header structure
header = xsd.Element(
    '{wsdl}AuthenticateRequest',
    xsd.ComplexType([xsd.Element("{wsdl}api_key", xsd.String())])
)

# Insert values into header placeholders
self._header_value = header(api_key=self.api_key)
```

**This does not work:**

```
from zeep import Client, xsd

# Generate the header structure
header = xsd.Element(
    'Header',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            '{wsdl}AuthenticateRequest',
            xsd.ComplexType([
                xsd.Element('{wsdl}api_key', xsd.String()),
            ])
        ),
        xsd.Element(
            'pager',
            xsd.ComplexType([
                xsd.Element('page', xsd.String()),
                xsd.Element('per_page', xsd.String()),
            ])
        ),
    ])
)

# ERROR HERE: Insert values into header placeholders
self._header_value = header(api_key=self.api_key, pager={'page':1,'per_page':100})
```

> **Error**: TypeError: ComplexType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_key'. Signature: AuthenticateRequest: {api_key: xsd:string}, pager: {page: xsd:string, per_page: xsd:string}

**This also does not work:**

```
header = xsd.Element(
    '{wsdl}AuthenticateRequest',
    xsd.ComplexType([xsd.Element("{wsdl}api_key", xsd.String())]),
    xsd.Element(
        'pager',
        xsd.ComplexType([
            xsd.Element('page', xsd.String()),
            xsd.Element('per_page', xsd.String()),
        ])
    )
)

# ERROR HERE: Insert values into header placeholders
self._header_value = header(api_key=self.api_key, pager={"page":1,"per_page":100})
```

*'pager' is not defined in the wsdl but the server expects that it could be there.*

> TypeError: ComplexType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pager'.
> Signature: `api_key: xsd:string`

**Recent Failed (2022) Attempt Using @markoan answer**:

```
def get_pager(self, page: int = 1, per_page: int = 100):
    """ Create header that contains the page and records per page. """

    pager_header = xsd.Element(
        'pager',
        xsd.ComplexType([
            xsd.Element(
                'page', xsd.Integer()
            ),
            xsd.Element(
                'per_page', xsd.Integer()
            )
        ])
    )

    return pager_header(page=page, per_page=per_page)

def call(self, endpoint: str, *args, **kwargs):
    """Allows calling of any client service defined in the WSDL."""

    # get the endpoint
    endpoint = getattr(self.client.service, endpoint)

    # get SOAP authentication header which includes the API key embedded from CFG
    headers = [self.get_header()]

    # add the pager complex element to headers if required in kwargs
    if page := kwargs.get("page"):
        per_page = kwargs.get("per_page") or 100
        headers.append(self.get_pager(page, per_page))

    # call the endpoint with provided unnamed and named parameters if any
    result = endpoint(*args, **kwargs, _soapheaders=headers)

    # serialize and return result
    return self.serialize(result)
```

**What is the simplest way using Zeep to set the namespace api_key and non-namespaced complex pager element?**

Comment: Have you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963114/python-zeep-soap-complex-header

Comment: Yes, I’ve attempted altering that solution to fit the pattern of my API, but was not successful. My second failed example listed above is built off of that answer. I’ll try again though.

Comment: Could you share the WSDL to better test a possible solution?

Comment: @Markoan I wish I could, it’s proprietary and extensive and contractually prevents sharing. The specification listed at the start of the question is what is expected by the server. It works without the pager element, but the server will respond to a change in the page and per_page nodes if let’s say I can send page 2 and per_page 1000 in a properly formatted soapheader.

Comment: @Markoan So it comes down to just creating the spec in the proper format with Zeep.

Comment: @Liquidgenius I posted an answer for building the header. Hope this helps you and anyone with this question.

Comment: @Markoan Thank you for a very comprehensive answer. I’ll leave this up for a while before accepting to see if any other answers are posted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I find it's easier to work with Zeep if we have a valid and complete WSDL.

A simple API service WSDL that expects an element without namespace would import a schema with no namespace like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" >
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:import schemaLocation="namespaceLessElement.xsd"/>
      <s:element name="Api" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="ApiResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ApiResult" type="s:int"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="apiKey">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="api_key" type="s:string"></s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ApiSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Api"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ApiSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ApiResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ApiKeyHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="ApiKeyHeaderParam" element="tns:apiKey"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PagerHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="PagerHeaderParam" ref="pager"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ApiSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Api">
      <wsdl:documentation>This is a test WebService. Returns a number</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ApiSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ApiSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ApiSoap" type="tns:ApiSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Api">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Api" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header message="tns:ApiKeyHeader" part="ApiKeyHeaderParam" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:PagerHeader" part="PagerHeaderParam" use="literal"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ApiTest">
    <wsdl:port name="ApiSoap" binding="tns:ApiSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://superpc:8082/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

With namespaceLessElement.xsd:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<s:schema xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <s:element name="pager">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element name="page" type="s:int"></s:element>
        <s:element name="per_page" type="s:int"></s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
</s:schema>
```

Note how the operation definition that expects header values points to correct messages:

```xml
<wsdl:operation name="Api">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Api" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:header message="tns:ApiKeyHeader" part="ApiKeyHeaderParam" use="literal"/>
    <soap:header message="tns:PagerHeader" part="PagerHeaderParam" use="literal"/>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and these in turn reference correct elements:

```xml
<wsdl:message name="ApiKeyHeader">
  <wsdl:part name="ApiKeyHeaderParam" element="tns:apiKey"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PagerHeader">
  <wsdl:part name="PagerHeaderParam" ref="pager"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

You should check in the WSDL of your web service that the operation describes both headers and that it includes a schema definition for both elements. In the example WSDL the service namespace is `targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"` but this should point to your web service URL.

So assuming your WSDL is valid and complete, we need to define the Client pointing to the WSDL and then set the header values using the `_soapheaders` parameter, similar to the method I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350313/1748460) but building the content reference. Zeep can take care of the different namespaces but I found issues with empty ones:

```python
transport = Transport(cache=SqliteCache())
self.Test = Client(wsdl='http://my-endpoint.com/production.svc?wsdl', transport=transport)

# Header objects
apiKey_header = xsd.Element(
    '{http://tempuri.org/}apiKey',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            'api_key', xsd.String()
        )
    ])
)

pager_header = xsd.Element(
    'pager',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            'page', xsd.Integer()
        ),
        xsd.Element(
            'per_page', xsd.Integer()
        )
    ])
)

apiKey_header_value = apiKey_header( api_key=key)
pager_header_value = pager_header( page=page, per_page=perpage)

# Request
response = self.Test.service.Api( _soapheaders=[apiKey_header_value, pager_header_value] )

logger.debug("Result={1}".format(response))

# Prints: Result=2 (or whatever value the test API sends)
```

EDIT: Example of generated XML request:

```xml
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <ns0:apiKey xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
         <api_key>1230011</api_key>
      </ns0:apiKey>
      <pager>
         <page>2</page>
         <per_page>10</per_page>
      </pager>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <ns0:Api xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/"/>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Make sure that the header that has a namespace is defined with the correct URL.

If you still have problems it may mean your WSDL does not define all elements or that it's not linking correctly to external XSDs. In those cases one option is to save a local copy os the WSDL and linked XSDs, then edit the files to fix references and then point Zeep to that local file instead.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I am sure this will prove useful to others as well. I’ve marked it accepted.

Comment: how do I point my client.service.X to a local file when it has no headers?

Comment: @markoan Revisiting this API some time later. I can confirm that the WSDL does not have the pager element defined. I've run a text search on it for pager, page and per_page with no results and checked manually. I've also tried to get the Pager as a complex type from the factory, and while I can get other complex types it will not return the pager. When attempting your solution I throw an error TypeError: ComplexType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page'. Signature: ``. I've updated my answer with the attempt.

So is my only option to manually update the WSDL locally?

Comment: As noted at https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/headers.html it is possible to pass an lxml Element object if the wsdl doesn't define a soap header but the server expects it. No example provided.

Comment: @markoan, I've rebountied this question for a working answer, if you have any additional insights, I would love to hear them.